# Проблема с методом "Load()"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возникла проблема с загрузкой страницы в блок. Использую подключение библиотеки JQuery с помощью `src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"`.
Через событие `body - onload` реализую загрузка страницы в div с помощью `$('#lane').load('posts\1.html');`.
В итоге браузер выдаёт ошибку

```
jquery-latest.js:9631 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC/Desktop/%D0%....ПУТЬ К СТРАНИЦЕ.../1.html.
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

В чём именно неурядица и проблема, я не понимаю, ибо JQuery никогда раньше не использовал. Изучал чисто javascript.

Comment: Разные протоколы расцениваются как разные ресурсы. Вы с другого протокола считываете file://

Comment: А возможно конкретнее описать причину? И желательно с примером реализации. Ибо я не так уж хорош ещё в веб-программировании.)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Вообщем, как я в итоге-то понял: на деле с AJAX-запросами, будь они самописные или реализованы с помощью JQuery, нужно работать через виртуальный сервер или непосредственно заливать на сервер. Всё так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка не из-за `jQuery`.
В описании даётся понятный ответ: запрос к `%your_path%` провалился, т. к. AJAX-запрос запрещен политикой безопасности браузера из-за того, что `CORS` не поддерживает протокол `file://`, только:

> http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource

Правда поддержка протокола не гарантирует ответ, нужны правильные заголовки, [см. больше](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Comment: Благодарю. Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Валес, пожалуйста, примите ответ для потомков :)